# what does git man pages [<file-option>] mean

Tags: git, git-config, manpage

I am reading the man pages of git-config , you can check it here too.

https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config/1.8.3

In synopsis , I am unable to understand what does `[<file-option>]` mean , I have tried to look into its details of the man pages but not successful. May be its some linux or man pages thing. I know what does `[]` and `<>` means but cannot get what does file-option means here.

Your help is much appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: @phd I agree OP could have read the `git config` man page more carefully and eventually figured it out, but this question is not a duplicate of the one you suggest: OP didn't want to know what `[]` meant, they wanted to know what `<file-option>` stood for, which was not obvious at first because they forgot to backtick `[<file-option>]`, and the inner part of interpreted as html and hidden - I just fixed that.

Comment: Ok, retracted...

Answer (score 2):

In the `git config` manpage, `[<file-option>]` stand for optionally using one of `--system`, `--global`, `--local`, or `--file <filename>`, which tell `git config` which file to work with in the rest of the command.

I agree that could have been made a bit more clear in that man page.